# Plotting modified data in gnuplot

Tags: ubuntu, gnuplot

I have generated a data file named *silicon.dos* while performing Density Functional Theory (DFT) calculations using [Quantum Espresso](https://www.quantum-espresso.org/) on Ubuntu.

The data file looks like this:
[image]

I plotted it using the code  `plot "silicon.dos" with lines` on gnuplot and it looks like this.
[image]

Now I want to replot it with the values of Energy (eV) on the x-axis (which is in column 2, as seen from the picture of the data file) subtracted by 7 and the DOS (E) on the y-axis should remain the same. My aim is to reproduce the same curves with just the x axis shifted by 7 in the negative direction. So I browsed online and tried the code `plot "silicon.dos" using ($2-7):($3)`. It turned out to be like this: [image]

This is definitely  not what I wanted. So how do I go about it?

Comment: Hi Shaona, for the future it is better to add the 5-8 lines of your data file instead of the image, so that if anyone wants he/she can try what you did ... BTW by default `gnuplot` with the data `plot” .dat "" assumes "plot" data.dat "using 1:2` or if you prefer `using ($1):($2)`. So if you have no special settings I cannot imagine as you were able to generate the first figure with a simple `plot "silicon.dos" with lines`.

Answer (score 2):

I think the column number you specified is off by one.

> the values of Energy (eV) on the x-axis (which is in column 2, as seen from the picture of the data file)

The image is a snapshot of the editor screen. The leftmost integer (1,2,3,...) is what the editor is displaying and is not included in the data file "silicon.dos", right?

So your plot command will look like this

```
plot "silicon.dos" using ($1-7):($2)
```